# Is it possible to create a Python Email Sender app using my Google SMTP?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

I would like to make a Python email sending app, many people told me that Google has disabled SMTP since 2022 or 2023 and it is impossible to enable it. They told me that I should use other mail providers, but I absolutely adored Gmail. Can anyone please answer my question and help me?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### SUGGESTION

You can check out these links as a starting point to create the Python email sender application/script. *Note that I do not own them*

[Send mail from your Gmail account using Python](https://tutorialspoint.com/send-mail-from-your-gmail-account-using-python)
[Send Emails With Python Using Gmail’s Free SMTP Mail Server API](https://medium.com/@Tanweer_Ali/send-emails-for-free-using-gmails-api-in-python-5b56c38d9a36)

###### GOOGLE DISABLED SMTP

Assuming that you have a personal Gmail account and not Google Workspace, you are correct that Google has disabled SMTP via less secure applications, as stated on [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255). Notice that this link is not working as well if you log in with a regular Google account. [Less secure app access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

However, you can still use app passwords that are available in Google accounts as a workaround. You may refer to this link for more information. [Sign in with app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833). Just enable 2-Step Verification and go to this link to generate one. [App passwords](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords)

---

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the links and articles provided.